# Changing the Access date format

Tags: date, ms-access, datepicker, format

In an Access form, I need to use the date output from a date picker field to be used to search for a file in a form. However, the default data format seems to only allow slashes. Although I know the date is being stored as a number in the database.

Put simply, I need `Me.myDate` to output a legal file name structure, for example, `yy-mm-dd`. Then I can concatenate that with my file name to search for `myfilename_yy-mm-dd`

I always get `myfilename_yy/mm/dd` which is of course unusable as a file name.

Changing the format of the field obviously makes no difference to how the value is stored. What I don't understand is if the date is stored as a number, and the output is shown in the selected format, how I can override the default formatting behaviour used when I query the date.

Answer (score 3):

The [Format Function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Format-Function-6f29d87b-8761-408d-81d3-63b9cd842530) will allow you to format the date as you wish.

An expression to include the formatted date in a filename pattern could look like this ...

```vb
"myfilename_" & Format(Me.myDate, "yy-mm-dd") & "*"
```

Comment: OMG. That's it! I had been trying with the format function, but hadn't been doing it correctly. Thank you so much!