# How to Modify Date in Access

Tags: ms-access

I am working with MS ACCESS and I want to modify the date to be displayed.

the code is:
=Now()
Output:
Sunday, March 2, 2019

I want to remove "Sunday" from the date in Sunday, March 2, 2019.

Can you help me with this problem please.
Thank you

Comment: This question has been asked before, in various forms. The information in the answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33249728/changing-the-access-date-format provides the information you need, using the Format function.

Comment: So, Johnny, how did you solve it?

Answer (score -1):

Set the *Format* property of the control bound to the expression (in your question) to:

```
mmmm d, yyyy
```